# Cadastrar dados recebidos de api com php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou com problema para salvar dados recebido por uma api no banco de dados com php, sempre me retorna o erro: Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro!

Já verifiquei os dados que estão sendo inseridos com print_r($sql) e esta tudo ok.
Não sei mais o que fazer.

Javascript no index:

```
$(function() {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'user_token': 'aqui_vai_o_meu_token',
                },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'http://moviecom.com.br/MoviecomAPI/',
                data: {
                    'praca': 'JAU',
                    'data_ini': '2018-05-10',
                    'data_fim': '2018-05-20'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    const filmes = response.data[0].filmes;

                    if(response.status == "Success") {
                        $(filmes).each( function (i, el){

                            const filme = el.filme;

                            $.post("salvar.php", {

                                titulo: filme.titulo,
                                cartaz: filme.cartaz,
                                sinopse: filme.sinopse,
                                genero: filme.genero

                            }, function(titulo){
                                $(".titulo").html(titulo);
                            })

                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(response.data[0]);
                    }   
                }
            }).fail(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        })
```

salvar.php:

```
<?php

include("conexao.php");

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$cartaz = $_POST['cartaz'];
$sinopse = $_POST['sinopse'];
$genero = $_POST['genero'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO filme (TITULO', 'CARTAZ', 'SINOPSE', 'GENERO') values ($titulo, $cartaz, $sinopse, $genero)";
print_r($titulo);

mysqli_query($conect, $sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");

$response = array("success" => true);

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

conexao.php:

```
<?php

    //conexão com o servidor
    $conect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "teste");

    // Caso a conexão seja reprovada, exibe na tela uma mensagem de erro
    if (!$conect) die (
        "<h1>Falha na conexão com o Banco de Dados!</h1>"
    );
?>
```

Comment: Deu certo minha resposta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está aqui:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO filme (TITULO', 'CARTAZ', 'SINOPSE', 'GENERO') values ($titulo, $cartaz, $sinopse, $genero)";
```

1 - O campo `TITULO` está escrito TITULO' com apenas uma aspas. Isso gera um erro de sintaxe.

2- Os valores que provavelmente são em CHAR ou VARCHAR estão SEM aspas simples.

O certo seria algo assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO filme (`TITULO`, `CARTAZ`, `SINOPSE`, `GENERO`) values ('$titulo', '$cartaz', '$sinopse', '$genero')";
```

O `print_r($sql)` não vai mostrar o erro.

Comment: Consegie solucionar apenas colocando a chamada assim: "INSERT INTO filme (TITULO, CARTAZ, SINOPSE, GENERO) values ('".$titulo."', "'.$cartaz'"., '".$sinopse."', "'.$genero."')";

Comment: @IgorFaria também dá. Mas a minha resposta está correta certo?

Comment: Se ela solucionou seu problema, por favor aprove-a. Isso ajuda a comunidade e dá um gás para que outras pessoas se interessem em responder suas próximas perguntas, se houver. Abraço!